# Efficient way to read non-empty cells in a column in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, large-files, import-from-csv

I have a large python file (>500,000 rows), and would like to read non-empty cells in a column in the dataframe (panda). Right now, I am doing this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

myiter = []    

    for xiter, x in enumerate(df['Column_name']):

        if (np.isnan(x) == False):
            myiter.append(xiter)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are they tagged as `NaN` in your `df`?

if yes then do

```
df.dropna()
```

Comment: I realized it drops all the rows, even if the given column doesn't have NaN (as other columns may also have NaN). Is there a way to drop only the rows with NaN in the specified column?

Comment: that would be impossible, how would you drop col 1 value if you want to keep col 2 value and keep the index? if you want to create a df out of a column without the na's you could do `newdf = df['Column_name'].dropna()`

Comment: I meant, I just want them in a list/array (not necessarily a df).

Comment: data2 = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 20},{'b':5,'c':10}]  
                             
pd.DataFrame(data2)  
Out[329]:  
     a   b     c  
0  1.0   2   NaN  
1  5.0  10  20.0  
2  NaN   5  10.0  
                  
pd.DataFrame(data2).dropna()  
Out[330]:  
     a   b     c  
1  5.0  10  20.0

Comment: I finally got what I was looking for:                                                pd.DataFrame(df[column_name]).dropna().iloc[:][column_name]

Comment: wo, this is the exact same thing hhas `newdf = df['Column_name'].dropna()` then `print(newdf)`